# Nested namspace javascript

Tags: javascript, namespaces, nested

I'm writing a user interface in javascript, it will take data from the HTML and pass it through an API using javascript. I am trying to take the data and pass it to a function without writing a bunch of if statements. However some actions have the actions are the same names in other controllers. So I have a nested namespace, now I can't get to the nested function. Hopefully someone can help.

Everything before this works fine.

```
var apiHandler = {
    user: {
        login: function(){
            console.log("test");
        }

    }
};

function callAPI(apiObject){
            //console.log(apiObject);
    var apiData = JSON.stringify(apiObject);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'https://dev.tragicstudios.com/clients/trego/api/index.php',
        data: {'enc_request':apiData},
        dataType: 'json',           
        success: function(data){
            var apiFunction = apiObject.controller+"."+apiObject.action;
            console.log(apiFunction);
            apiHandler["user.login"]();
            return data;
        }           
    });
}
```

Comment: The expression `apiObject.controller+"."+apiObject.action`, when evaluated, will try to output a string.  It will call `toString` on your objects, and then place a `'.'` between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the controller and action part as separate keys, instead of combining them:

```
apiHandler[apiObject.controller][apiObject.action]();
```

Comment: Well not I feel stupid... that makes sense and it worked. Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

For this specific example, instead of:

```
        apiHandler["user.login"]();
```

Try

```
        apiHandler["user"]["login"]();
```